# Java MySQL Insert produces a very long line - Regex

Tags: java, mysql, regex

I have written a Java Class that receives a text, parses it and stores it in a MySQL database.

In most cases, the result is very well parsed, but sometimes I get the following results:

This is my main problem! It seems like I have a lot of spaces that make my Insert so big.

```
+------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
| mail_text                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                          |
+------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
| Amt
Security B S A S Bench B Px A Px B Z A Z A YT Out Mood S&P Notes
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
GS 4½ 16 51/46 OBL 2¾ 16 105.43-105.50 23/18 0.34 1.25MM Baa1 A-

{IMGR<GO>}

             |
+------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
```

So it seems, that my regex is not that good, because it could terminate before instead of doing such a long line.

Following you find my regex:

```
        parsedBody = body.toString().replaceAll("(?m)(^ *| +(?= |$))", "").replaceAll("(?m)^$([\r\n]+?)(^$[\r\n]+?^)+", "$1");
```

This one should delete more than two following spaces and replace it with only one and delete every empty line:

```
"     This is the    example


of what I want to achieve    "
```

Result should be:

```
"This is the example
of what I want to achieve"
```

UPDATE:
@
I tried your regex expression, but I still do not get the result I wanted using it.
This is an example I receive via Email:

```
** GS ARGID 4¼'22  98¼/99  ||  8⅜'19 96/97











                   ARDAGH
```

which should be:

```
** GS ARGID 4¼'22  98¼/99  ||  8⅜'19 96/97
ARDAGH
```

I would be open for any advice!

Comment: [MySQL sucks](https://duckduckgo.com/?q=mysql+sucks). [Choose something else](http://grimoire.ca/mysql/choose-something-else).

Answer (score 0):

This would work for your case.

```
String s = "     This is the    example\n" + 
                "\n" + 
                "\n" + 
                "of what I want to achieve    ";
System.out.println(s.replaceAll("([\\r\\n])+", "$1").replaceAll("(?m)^ +| +$|(?<= ) +", ""));
```

**Output:**

```
This is the example
of what I want to achieve
```

`([\\r\\n])+` matches one or more line breaks and captures only the last.

Comment: I tried your regex, but I do not achive the desired result, I updated one more example in my question. I also still have the problem from the first result where I have very long text in the MySQL table where I want it ending after the "notes" field

Answer (score 0):

You are actually trying to achieve three separate things here: 1) replace multiple newlines with just one, 2) replace multiple space characters with just one, and 3) trim the string. To achieve all three, you have to do:

```
String test = "     This is the    example\n" +
        "\n" +
        "\n" +
        "of what I want to achieve    ";
String result = test.replaceAll("("+System.getProperty("line.separator")+")+", "$1").replaceAll("[ ]+", " ").trim();
```